# C# VS2015 - Can't call method from file in same project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inheritance, methods

I'm working on an assignment from a class right now and for some strange reason I'm having trouble calling a method from another file in the same project. I've tried researching solutions but every one always says that they're not in the same project, even though they are. I'm trying to use methods from another .cs file in my project in my Global.asax.cs file, so I don't know if that's what the problem is. I'm sure I did all the inheritance right, and that everything is in the same namespace.

Global.asax file:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/global.asax.cs" 
Inherits="Global" %>

<script runat="server">
---------------------------
---------------------------
---------------------------
</script>
```

Header for Global.asax.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace nvdWebService
{
     public class nvdTimer : System.Web.HttpApplication
     ....
     if(downloadNewFile()) /**method I'm trying to call**/
```

File I'm trying to call method from:

```
namespace nvdWebService
{
    public class cNVDdownload
    { ....
         private Boolean downloadNewFile()
         {
         ...
         }
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Post the code.  It's important to know not just what you are trying to accomplish, but how.  The .cs file and the Global.asax.cs code are important.

Comment: It would be more clear if you could explain that with an example, specifically what is happening. 

Also, the file could be inside the project folder, but file reference may not be in the project, or you moved the file, and now the file reference needs to be reconfigured.

Comment: Updated just now

Comment: You can't call a (non-`static`) method of a class without an instance and you cannot call `private` methods outside of the class itself

Answer (score 0):

A private method in a class cannot be accessed anywhere outside the class.
so, first the method access modifier need to be changed from private to public or internal. Read more about [access modifiers here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers).

To access a public/internal method in a different class, the method either 
1. needs to be a static method 
or
2. you need to create an instance of the class first and then access the method.

to make a method static: change the method signature to

```
public static Boolean downloadNewFile()
{

}
```

and then from global.asax.cs, call it like {{className}}.{{MethodName}}:

```
if(cNVDdownload.downloadNewFile())
```

second option is to create a new instance of cNVDdownload class and then access the method like:

```
var cNV = new cNVDdownload();
if (cNV.downloadNewFile())
{
}
```